# round a value to .0 or .5

Tags: javascript, formula, double

I'm looking for a way to round a value to .0 or to .5,

so 1,34 would become 1.5, 
   1.22 would become 1.0,
   1.63 would become 1.5,
   and 1.79 would become 2.0.

Is there a function to accomplish this or would I have to make my own?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to do this in JavaScript, in a Visualforce formula or in Apex code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is my solution:
I made my own function that would return the correct value

```
public Double myFunction(double input){         
    Double temp = Math.floor(input);
    input -= temp;
    if (input >= 0.5) return temp + 0.5;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ceil and floor Math functions to achieve this. Take a look on this document for examples,

http://mysalesforcecode.blogspot.in/2012/11/floor-function-in-salesforce.html

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KRnWAAW

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_math.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I have figured out my own method(which is quite simple actually) Here is what I did:
double myFunction(double input)
{
Double temp = Math.floor(input);
input -= temp;
if (input >= 0.5) return temp + 0.5;
return temp;
}

Comment: Great! Then, is that possible to create your own answer here for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ROUND(Value * 2)/2
```

Example:

We want 5.3 to become 5.5

```
5.3 * 2 ==> 10.6 
Round(10.6) ==> 11
11/2 ==> 5.5
```

**Floor** and **Ceiling** also work with this method.

We can even make work with 0.25 values. We just multiply by 4.

Example: make 5.3 as 5.25

```
5.3 * 4 ==> 21.2
Round(21.2) ==> 21
21/4 ==> 5.25
```